# looking for a better way of parsing XML retrieved from web API c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

I've been trying to parse XML retrieved from a web api all day. This is the only implementation I've found that worked for me. I tried with the Serializer class but couldn't seem to get it working.

Some of the Web APIs I need to get data from to have many elements and this implementation doesn't seem very scale-able...

I'm relatively new to this so any help is appreciated. What would be ideal is if somebody could show me how to have the same functionality as shown, using less code.. I imagine using the serializer class.

```
List<OpeningHours> openingHoursList = new List<OpeningHours>();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Uri geturi = new Uri("Insert Uri name");

HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(geturi);         
string response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);

foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("OpenHours"))
{
    openingHoursList.Add(new OpeningHours() { 
        DayOfWeek = item.Element("DayOfWeek").Value.ToString(),
        CloseTime = item.Element("CloseTime").Value.ToString(),
        OpenTime = item.Element("OpenTime").Value.ToString()
    });
}
```

For reference, this is the XML that I'm currently trying to parse.

```
<NewDataSet>
<OpenHours>
<DayOfWeek>Wednesday </DayOfWeek>
<OpenTime>07:30:00</OpenTime>
<CloseTime>18:00:00</CloseTime>
</OpenHours>
<OpenHours>
<DayOfWeek>Thursday </DayOfWeek>
<OpenTime>07:30:00</OpenTime>
<CloseTime>18:00:00</CloseTime>
</OpenHours>
<OpenHours>
<DayOfWeek>Monday </DayOfWeek>
<OpenTime>07:30:00</OpenTime>
<CloseTime>18:00:00</CloseTime>
</OpenHours>
<OpenHours>
<DayOfWeek>Tuesday </DayOfWeek>
<OpenTime>07:30:00</OpenTime>
<CloseTime>18:00:00</CloseTime>
</OpenHours>
<OpenHours>
<DayOfWeek>Friday </DayOfWeek>
<OpenTime>07:30:00</OpenTime>
<CloseTime>18:00:00</CloseTime>
</OpenHours>
</NewDataSet>
```

However, what is I wanted to parse something like this...

This is what I mean by scale-able. If I use my current solution I'll need to Initialise every field of my C# class by hand. As well as this, some of the XML elements have varying numbers of decedents...

```
<Dish>
<DishID>180</DishID>
<DishName>Caesar Salad (v) - Large</DishName>
<DishDesc>
Romaine Lettuce, Homemade Croutons, Shaved Grana Padano, Black Pepper & Caesar Dressing (separate) (v)
</DishDesc>
<DishPrice>21.5000</DishPrice>
<DishCat>22</DishCat>
<DishPosition>6</DishPosition>
<DishSpecial>0</DishSpecial>
<DishOn>true</DishOn>
<DishNumber/>
<DishHasOptions>false</DishHasOptions>
<VATable>true</VATable>
<UPC/>
<SKU/>
<Timer>0</Timer>
<FilterClasses/>
<DishDesc2/>
</Dish>
<Dish>
<DishID>179</DishID>
<DishName>Caesar Salad (v) - Small.</DishName>
<DishDesc/>
<DishPrice>4.3000</DishPrice>
<DishCat>22</DishCat>
<DishPosition>7</DishPosition>
<DishSpecial>0</DishSpecial>
<DishOn>true</DishOn>
<DishNumber/>
<DishHasOptions>false</DishHasOptions>
<VATable>true</VATable>
<UPC/>
<SKU/>
<Timer>0</Timer>
<FilterClasses/>
<DishDesc2/>
</Dish>
<Dish>
<DishID>53</DishID>
<DishName>Caesar salad (v)(small or large)</DishName>
<DishDesc>
Romaine lettuce, parmesan shavings, croutons with Caesar dressing
</DishDesc>
<DishPrice>4.0000</DishPrice>
<DishCat>7</DishCat>
<DishPosition>4</DishPosition>
<DishSpecial>0</DishSpecial>
<DishOn>false</DishOn>
<DishNumber>0</DishNumber>
<DishHasOptions>true</DishHasOptions>
<VATable>true</VATable>
<UPC/>
<SKU/>
<Timer>0</Timer>
<FilterClasses/>
<DishDesc2/>
<Option>
<DishOptionID>62</DishOptionID>
<DishID>53</DishID>
<DishOptionDesc>Select your size</DishOptionDesc>
<DishOptionSeqNo>1</DishOptionSeqNo>
<DishOptionPickerType>3</DishOptionPickerType>
<SubOption>
<dishSubOptionID>955</dishSubOptionID>
<DishOptionID>62</DishOptionID>
<DishSubOptionDesc>Small</DishSubOptionDesc>
<DishSubOptionPrice>0.0000</DishSubOptionPrice>
<DefaultChoice>true</DefaultChoice>
<DishID>53</DishID>
<DishSubOptionSeqNo>0</DishSubOptionSeqNo>
</SubOption>
<SubOption>
<dishSubOptionID>956</dishSubOptionID>
<DishOptionID>62</DishOptionID>
<DishSubOptionDesc>Large</DishSubOptionDesc>
<DishSubOptionPrice>15.0000</DishSubOptionPrice>
<DefaultChoice>false</DefaultChoice>
<DishID>53</DishID>
<DishSubOptionSeqNo>0</DishSubOptionSeqNo>
</SubOption>
</Option>
</Dish>
```

Comment: Since you want information on what you did wrong. #1: Don't bump your posts, by adding **answers** that aren't answers. If it's not attracting enough attention, edit it, and clarify and add more details. If it's still not attracting enough attention, consider helping others to gain rep, and you can put a bounty on the question. #2: Don't edit your post to add information not relevant to the question. (Your last edit did not clarify your question at all). I highly recommend you read [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @FrankerZ I've edited my question, hopefully it makes more sense now. I'll be sure to read the link that you have sent. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want shorter code, you're looking for a Linq Select method here, something like:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

...

```
List<OpeningHours> openingHoursList = doc.Descendants("OpenHours").Select(x => new OpeningHours()
{
    DayOfWeek = x.Element("DayOfWeek").Value.ToString(),
    CloseTime = x.Element("CloseTime").Value.ToString(),
    OpenTime = x.Element("OpenTime").Value.ToString()
}).ToList();
```

Getting used to lambdas and creating and assigning variables in the same statement will help you write shorter code, but the shortest code isn't always the best option, for instance where scalability and maintainability are also a priority.

Because you haven't provided much by way of examples of the XML you want to parse, there's little more that I can safely recommend - I've not found a single, self-scaling XML-parsing approach that will elegantly handle a variety of purposes. 
Another approach I have used in the past is to shift the focus onto the data class itself, in this case OpeningHours.
In your OpeningHours class, create a constructor that accepts an XElement as parameter, and write the code to validate and parse that XML in there:

```
//in your OpeningHours class:
public OpeningHours(XElement xmlResponse)
{
    DayOfWeek = xmlResponse.Element("DayOfWeek").Value.ToString();
    CloseTime = xmlResponse.Element("CloseTime").Value.ToString();
    OpenTime = xmlResponse.Element("OpenTime").Value.ToString();
} //etc..
```

Then in your parsing method you replace the lambda in the .Select() with:

```
List<OpeningHours> openingHoursList = doc.Descendants("OpenHours")
     .Select(x => new OpeningHours(x)).ToList();
```

Building you classes this way helps keep the relevant logic together with the structure it is loaded into, and as new properties are added, I find it easier to update the relevant XML parsing routine.

Comment: I've added reference to what I'm trying to parse... I'm sure your answer still holds to what you've said. I just wanted to add clarity

Comment: Unfortunately, my reputation is below 15 and cannot mark any answer acceptable yet... When I have some reputation, I'll make sure to mark it acceptable. Thank you for your time.